# How to catch an error code 'wrong-password 'in the reauthenticateWithCredential();

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem, when I want to catch an exception on firebase auth

```
reauthenticateWithCredential();
```

it doesn't catch anything, any idea?

Here's the example code.

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        email: auth.currentUser!.email.toString(),
        password: password.toString());
    UserCredential userCredential =
        await auth.currentUser!.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);

on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
        print("Wrong password");}
```

result :

```
 E/flutter (11690): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
```

it didn't catch the "wrong-password" code

I try to catch the same problem with the login function, and it works

here's an example:

```
 

    void login(String email, String password) async {
        try {
          await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    
          Get.offAllNamed(Routes.HOME);
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
            print("Wrong password");}
```

result :

```
    I/flutter (11690): Wrong password
```

it catches the "wrong-password" code

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a FlutterFire Auth issues, try this:

```
on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
        print("Wrong password");}
```

Comment: doesn't work, still facing same issues:(

Comment: i searched and I found some similar issues that might help you, https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/3488, https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/3475#issuecomment-689460431